# Vhosts with Apache on Debian - not showing the right page when accessing (landing on phpmyadmin login)

Tags: apache, server, phpmyadmin, debian, vhosts

I'm a beginner here and I have a website running on a VPS. I did manage to put up my website alone and give it an ssl certificate and all, and it was a tough process that I went through a long time ago and didn't dare to touch ever since as I am too much of a novice with these things.
Now I want to host another website on my VPS, so I just put the folder containing all my new website info into the html folder at var/www/ of my VPS, and added a new .conf file for my new website in the sites-enabled folder at etc/apache2. I just copied the conf that worked for my first website, adapting it to match the correct path to link accordingly to the right folder in my html folder. And I then did the en2site command to enable it.
On the other side I changed my domains DNS A record on the panel of my VPS provider to match the IP of my server, and it's been more than 24h since so it should have propagated.

PROBLEM: When I type in the address of my website in the address bar of my browser, it leads me to a login page of phpmyadmin.

What am I not doing right?

Thank you in advance for your answer, that I hope will not be too technical as I am still learning the ropes of these things. I am going to have to enable ssl for this site afterwards but I would like to have it work without before opening this new challenging chapter..

Kindly

Here is my vhost .conf file for this website:

```
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    NameVirtualHost 51.77.xxx.xxx:80
    ServerAdmin admin@xxx.at
    ServerName xxx.at
    ServerAlias www.xxx.at
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx.at/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.xxx.at [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxx.at
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>`
```